# apache cxf jaxrs register custom hibernate parameter constraint

Tags: cxf, hibernate-validator

I am using spring boot, apache cxf, jaxrs and hibernate validator . I am trying to create custom constraint for method parameter. Reason is that @Valid does not have groups.How do I register or add this to hibernate validator so that it behaves like @Valid ie ExecutableValidator. below is the code

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy=MyValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidInput {
    String message() default "com.xyz.message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}

@Provider
@Component
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidInput, Entity>  {

    private static Validator validator;

    private Class<?>[] groups ;

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload;

    static{
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidInput constraintAnnotation) {
        this.groups = constraintAnnotation.groups();
        this.payload = constraintAnnotation.payload();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Entity value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //logic here
    }


}
```

now, when I use the constraint on a rest service method parameter, the validator is not at all called . Instead of @Valid , I want to use `@ValidInput`.

pls help

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have Enabled Validation feature.

```
    @Bean
    public JAXRSBeanValidationFeature beanValidationFeature(){
        JAXRSBeanValidationFeature feature = new JAXRSBeanValidationFeature();
        return feature;
    }

    @Bean
    public ValidationExceptionMapper  validationExceptionMapper(){
        return new ValidationExceptionMapper();
    }
```

Comment: Ya i have enabled it. The in built constraints are working fine.

Comment: I tried the Validateonexecute annotation too. But it is not working. Not sure if am missing any configuration. I have started looking at spring validator which solves my requirement with @Validated. This allows to specify constraint group. But, I am eager to know what am i missing with hibernate validator

Comment: Can you check if JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor is being invoked by enabling cxf debug logs

Comment: Since the inbuilt constraints are working am assuming that interceptor is working. And, the custom constraint validator has a static block and i put a debug point there but it wasnt hit. So i thought the validator is not being called. I will check again and comment back